# How to place players in team based on how many player's they've killed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make two teams that are the "good guys" and the "bad guys".
I'd like it to be like a reputation system where you get good karma for killing bad guys and bad karma for killing anyone but the bad guys.

So far I'm using the following commands:

```
/scoreboard teams add Team1 Fugitives

/scoreboard teams option Team1 color red
```

and

```
/scoreboard teams add Team2 Rescuers

/scoreboard teams option Team2 color blue
```

I'd like use a command or a command within a command block to do something like the following.

```
if(playerkillsplayer = true){
variable + 1
}

if(playerkillsFugitive = true){
variable - 1
}

if(variable > 0 ){
team ==  Team1
}

if(variable < 1){
team == Team2
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you begin,

Use a scoreboard to detect kills:

```
/scoreboard objectives add kills playerKillCount
```

One for karma:

```
/scoreboard objectives add karma dummy Karma
```

One for deaths:

```
/scoreboard objectives add death dummy deathCount
```

And one for a time since last kill:

```
/scoreboard objectives add timeSinceKill dummy
```

Finally, have a clock with the following command:

```
/scoreboard players add @a timeSinceKill 1
```

## Now that the scoreboards are set up, let's begin.

For the first section of code:

```
if(playerkillsplayer = true){
variable + 1
}
```

Have the following three commands in a 20 tick clock, making sure that the third command is activated last:

```
/scoreboard players add @a[score_kills_min=1] karma 1
/scoreboard players set @a[score_kills_min=1] timeSinceKill 0
/scoreboard players set @a kills 0
```

For the second section:

```
if(playerkillsFugitive = true){
variable - 1
}
```

*Note: If you want people to be able to reverse their lost karma for killing a good person, change* `variable - 1` *to* `variable - 2` *I'm going to assume you want for people to be able to reverse, otherwise change the* `2` to `1` *in the commands.*

Now have the following commands on a clock powered in the following order:

*A limitation is that if another one killed another person in the last 1/10 of a second, it will be activated twice. However, this is very unlikely.*

```
/execute @a[score_death_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players remove @p[score_timeSinceKill=2] karma 2
/scoreboard players set @p death 0
```

Finally, the last two sections:

```
if(variable > 0 ){
team ==  Team1
}

if(variable < 1){
team == Team2
}
```

For the first section, on a clock have

```
/scoreboard teams join Team1 @a[score_karma_min=1]
```

Second, have a command on a clock:

```
/scoreboard teams join Team2 @a[score_karma=0]
```

Comment: You should **not** be using `/execute` in this manner. Firstly, you are mixing `@a`, which can target dead players, with `@p`, which cannot target dead players. While a dead player will run the `/scoreboard` command, they will not target themselves. Secondly, `/execute` should **only** be used when origin or sender needs to be changed, which is not the case. `/scoreboard` has a target selector for you to use, example: `/scoreboard players add @a[score_kills_min=1] karma 1`. Every case of `/execute` you have can be removed, as it otherwise only serves to increase server workload.

Comment: You were right, except for `/execute @a[score_death_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players remove @p[score_timeSinceKill=2] karma 2`. Here, I'm not trying to target the person with the death, but the other way around would require `/testfor`. I will fix the others, though.